# Указание сложности пароля

Tags: linux

Как требовать от всех пользователей использования сложного пароля для входа в систему (буквы, цифры и символы).

Comment: вроде нынче по умолчанию так и есть. или вы про организационные моменты, а не технические? // p.s. — «буквы, цифры» — это, кстати, «символы». наверно, вы подразумевали знаки препинания?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обычный подход — установить и настроить модуль `pam_cracklib`. Инструкций с точными последовательностями действий для конкретных дистрибутивов много в гугле по запрусу «*имя дистрибутива cracklib*», а общий принцип действий вкратце выглядит как-то так:

1. Собственно установить модуль `pam_cracklib.so`, обычно это отдельный пакет с именем вроде `pam-cracklib`. Обычно это так или иначе сразу включает его с параметрами по умолчанию.
2. Добавить/изменить строчку для этого модуля в подходящий файл в `/etc/pam.d/` (обычно «подходящий» — это тот, который включается в `/etc/pam.d/passwd`; в Gentoo, например, это `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`):

   ```
   password    required    pam_cracklib.so minlen=8 dcredit=-1 ocredit=-1 lcredit=0 ucredit=0 minclass=3
   ```

   Конкретные параметры стоит подбирать исходя из своих предпочтений. Здесь:

   - `minlen=8` — минимальная длина `8` символов
   - `dcredit=-1` — требовать одну цифру
   - `ocredit=-1` — требовать один спец. символ
   - `lcredit=0` — не уменьшать требование длины при использовании строчных букв
   - `ucredit=0` — не уменьшать требование длины при использовании заглавных букв
   - `minclass=3` — требовать 3 различных класса символов (строчные/заглавные/цифры/символы)

   Подробности по параметрам см. в [`man pam_cracklib`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_cracklib). По формату файла — в [`man pam.d`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/pam.d)